# Как заменить картинку на странице через JS

Tags: php, javascript, html

В html имеем картинку:

```
<img name = "himage" src="image.php?id=1&type=0" width="350"/>
```

В js пытаемся при клике по строке таблицы подменить:

```
  function getParentTag(node, tag){
    if (node){
      return (node.tagName == tag) ? node : getParentTag(node.parentElement, tag);
    }
    return null;
  }

  function onClick(e){
    var row = getParentTag(e.target, 'TR');
    if (!row){
      return;
    }
    idx = this.getAttribute('activeRowIndex');
    this.rows[idx].classList.remove('activeRow');
    row.classList.add('activeRow');
    this.setAttribute('activeRowIndex', row.rowIndex);
    id = row.cells[0].innerHTML;
    //Обновление картинки при клике на строку таблицы
    document.himage.scr = "image.php?id=" + id + "&type=0";
  }
```

В отладчике смотрю, всё изменяется... В коде страницы - нет. Нужно как-то заставить обновиться img? или проблема в том, что это не физический файл, а требуется запуск php?

PS: и ещё до кучи вопросик... **image.php** тянет картинку из базы данных, есть ли возможность как-то организовать кеширование, чтобы картинка, которая уже была загружена не запрашивалась у базы заново? (или этим браузеры автоматически занимаются?)

Comment: Да конечно, при смене у вас же не работает image.php. Сделайте подмену картинки через AJAX

Comment: @Arsen для меня пока ajax - страшное слово... старался никогда не использовать ничего лишнего, пока оно не нужно) потому jQuery и Ajax обходил стороной... Но он, похоже, имеет мощные средства для динамического изменения контента и стоит его изучить, думаю. Можете показать как оно там будет выглядеть?

Comment: Для использования Ajax необъязательно делать через JQuery. можно и на чистом JS сделать Ajax запрос, хотя на JQuery более удобно будет работать.

Comment: Если `image.php` принимает `GET` запрос и по нему отдает картинку в ответ, то ваш код должен работать.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, это точно? странность в том, что изменённую ссылку я могу видеть в дебаггере, но когда после изменения открываю текст страницы, то она не изменённая... Мне показалось это подозрительным. Может я что-то не так меняю?

Comment: Возможно, ошибки в консоли какие-то есть? Потому что должна быть измененная.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, консоль отображает только первый старт, дальше при кликах там тишина

Comment: Ну вот в этом и проблема, значит, у вас не верно отрабатывает js. Я надеюсь, вы под консолью понимаете консоль в браузере, например DevTools в Chrome?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, [document.himage.scr] тут что-то не то... этот аттрибут не влияет на картинку, хоть и вписывается... если меняю вместо него [outerHTML] то вместо картинки вижу нужный адрес. Под консолью я понимаю браузер/веб-инструменты/консоль в лисе

Comment: всё, я понял, что ошибся) какой scr, если должен быть src! Всё работает)

Comment: Во избежание таких опечаток лучше разрабатывать в каком-нибудь хорошем редакторе. Например, `Webstorm`.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, но при просмотре исходного кода всё равно ссылка остаётся первая... хоть и картинки меняются... но это не столь важно, наверное.

Comment: Такого не может быть. Или вы не у того элемент смотрите, или вы смотрите не тот исходный код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе ваш код должен работать, если `image.php` отдает картинку.

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fm08gvop/8/).

```js
function changeUrl(el) {
  document.himage.src = el.value;
}
```

```html
<img name="himage" height="250">
<ul>
  <li>
    <label> pic 1
<input onchange="changeUrl(this)" type="radio" name="imageUrl" value="https://static.pexels.com/photos/67843/splashing-splash-aqua-water-67843.jpeg">
</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label> pic 2
<input onchange="changeUrl(this)" type="radio" name="imageUrl" value="http://joombig.com/demo-extensions1/images/gallery_slider/Swan_large.jpg">
</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label> pic 3
<input onchange="changeUrl(this)" type="radio" name="imageUrl" value="https://vemco.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/image-banner2.jpg">
</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```